# How to check programmatically with Java if a network adapter is disabled on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, network-interface

In my code, I try to fetch all the network adapters. The "disconnected" network adapters are kept but those "disabled" ones need to be filtered out. (The "disabled" ones are those with a little arrow in the screenshot below).

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXOT7.png)

Currently, I'm using `java.net.NetworkInterface#getNetworkInterfaces` and iterate through the returned `java.net.NetworkInterface` objects. However, it doesn't have a method to check if the network interface is "disabled".

I guess there might be a way to read the NIC status from the registry, but I couldn't find it after googling for hours. Is there any other way to do it?

My environment:

- Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
- JDK 8

**The investigation I have made so far**

In the JDK native code, if “IPv6 Available” - it calls `Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_getMacAddr0_XP` https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/native/java/net/NetworkInterface.c#L1007 . This calls `getAdapter` which calls Windows' `GetAdaptersAddresses`. The flags are GAA_FLAG_SKIP_DNS_SERVER | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_MULTICAST | GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX. Since it does NOT include the GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_ALL_INTERFACES  flag, it does NOT include the hidden interface.

However, if NOT “IPv6 Available” - it calls `getIF` , which eventually calls `GetIfTable` that returns all interfaces (with mac addresses) INCLUDING hidden interface.

So it behaves differently depending on whether the IPv6 is available, we just have no way to control it.